# Spring 3 problems with TransactionManager and annotations

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I'm trying to setup a `TransactionManager` in my Web Application (powered by Spring MVC 3), as I need to have one method of a component annotated as `@Transactional`.

This is my situation:

- `web.xml`: load 2 xml files for the Spring `ContextLoaderListener` (`applicationContext.xml` and `database.xml`)
- applicationContext.xml: contains some beans which I can't define via annotation, plus the tags for annotation, plus the usual context:annotation-config and context:component-scan (this component-scan includes the package that contains the `@Transactional` method)
- `database.xml`: contains the datasource (I'm using `BasicDataSource` from commons-dbcp), the transaction manager definition and tx:annotation-driven.

I've got a `@Component` `(DeleteComponent`) which has an interface and an implementation (`DeleteComponentImpl`). The implementation class is annotated with `@Component` and has one public method annotated with `@Transactional` (I annotated the concrete class and not the interface, as Spring documentation states). For `@Transactional` I didn't put any arguments, as defaults are fine. This class has some DAOs (annotated with `@Repository`) being injected via `@Autowired`. I'm using only plain JDBC (no Hibernate or other ORM). This `@Component` is injected into a `@Controller` (which is defined in spring-`servlet.xml`).

If the method annotated as `@Transactional` throws an exception (unchecked, as `RuntimeException`), however, nothing is rolled back. The database retains the changes did before the exception. I'm using Jetty web server for testing locally my application. The thing I noticed is actually that seems like no transaction manager is being set up. Actually, my transaction manager is named `transactionManager`. The xml line to set up the annotation-driven transaction is

```xml
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

If I change it to use a non-existing bean name like

```xml
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="fake"/>
```

The application still deploys correctly and doesn't complain.

Any tips on what should I check to make it working?

Thanks.

Comment: why not import the database.xml from your main appcontext.xml? how is the appcontext defined in spring-servlet.xml pulled in? the component-scan base-package matches the package of your impl class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by using `@Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)` and switching from a `BasicDataSource` to a `ComboPooled` that's present in c3p0 library. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

To get rollback when an exception is thrown add this:

```java
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
```

You will also need to set up the transactionManger bean (here is mine, using hibernate) :

```xml
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
                p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

I found this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts1/index.html) informative.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, anyway I'm not using Hibernate, only plain JDBC and I've already configured my TransactionManager (added now the code in the question)

Comment: @Transactional rollbacks by default on RuntimeExceptions, so you would need the specify the rollbackFor attribute only if you want to rollback on checked exceptions also, or if you need a more fine-grained control (rollback on your custom exceptions, for example). The poster says the method is throwing a RuntimeException.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that `@Autowired` and `@Resource` aren't scanned by Spring on a `@Component`.
Try to use a `ContextHolder` class to get the context and the DAO

```
@Component
public class ContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {

    /** 
     * Spring context which will directly be injected by Spring itself
     */
    private static ApplicationContext context = null;

    /**
     * Overridden method of ApplicationContextAware, which will automatically be called by the container
     */
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**

    /**
     * Static method used to get the context
     */
    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

and call your dao with :

```
ContextHolder.getApplicationContext().getBean("MyDAO");
```

Comment: At least the @Autowired annotation works fine on a class annotated with @Component. I have used it many times.